# Create Azure container registry to save the docker images and defined the mechanism to remove the older docker images from the ACR

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-container-registry

i am beginner so can anyone give example or better idea using github action and terraform Create Azure container registry to save the docker images and defined the mechanism to remove the older docker images from the ACR

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment:**

I created an azure container registry with the image:

Code:

main.tf:

```
provider "docker" {

  registry_auth {
    address  = azurerm_container_registry.acr.login_server
    username = azurerm_container_registry.acr.admin_username
    password = azurerm_container_registry.acr.admin_password
  }
}

resource "docker_registry_image" "helloworld" {
  name = "mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-helloworld:latest"

  build {
    context    = "${path.cwd}/absolutePathToContextFolder"
    dockerfile = "Dockerfile"
  }
   
 }

resource "azurerm_container_registry" "acr" {
  name                = "kavyacontainerRegistry1"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  sku                 = "Premium"
  admin_enabled       = true
  georeplications {
    location                = "East US"
    zone_redundancy_enabled = true
    tags                    = {}
  }
  georeplications {
    location                = "North Europe"
    zone_redundancy_enabled = true
    tags                    = {}
  }
}
resource "azurerm_azuread_application" "acr-app" {
  name = "myacr-app"
}

resource "azurerm_azuread_service_principal" "acr-sp" {
  application_id = "${azurerm_azuread_application.acr-app.application_id}"
}

resource "azurerm_azuread_service_principal_password" "acr-sp-pass" {
  service_principal_id = "${azurerm_azuread_service_principal.acr-sp.id}"
  value                = "Pass3ffgg"
  end_date             = "2022-08-08T01:02:03Z"
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "acr-assignment" {
  scope                = "${azurerm_container_registry.acr.id}"
  role_definition_name = "Contributor"
  principal_id         = "${azurerm_azuread_service_principal_password.acr-sp-pass.service_principal_id}"
}

   resource "null_resource" "docker_push" {
      provisioner "local-exec" {
      command = <<-EOT
        docker login ${azurerm_container_registry.acr.login_server} 
        docker push ${azurerm_container_registry.acr.login_server}
      EOT
      }
    }

resource "azurerm_container_group" "example" {
  name                = "kaexample-container"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  ip_address_type     = "Public"
  dns_name_label      = "kavyaaci-label"
  os_type             = "Linux"

  container {
    name   = "hello-world"
    image  = "mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-helloworld:latest"
    cpu    = "0.5"
    memory = "1.5"

    ports {
      port     = 443
      protocol = "TCP"
    }
  }

  tags = {
    environment = "testing"
  }
}
```

[image]

> To send the image to your own registry, the registry domain has to be
> prepended to the image name.
>
> example if   mcr.microsoft.com is prepended to the image xxx:xxx
> would be pushed to the registry mcr.microsoft.com instead of
> DockerHub.

[image]

As there are no old images yet in my registry,
Try  delete yours using the command in the

```
  resource "null_resource" "docker_push" {
          provisioner "local-exec" {
          command = <<-EOT
            PURGE_CMD="acr purge --filter 'hello-world:.*' \
                         --untagged –ago 1d"
                          
       az acr run \  --cmd "$PURGE_CMD" \    --registry myregistry807 \ /dev/null    
             EOT
          }
        }
```

Or use

```
az acr repository delete -n MyRegistry --repository MyRepository --tag MyTag
```

in the place of command

Reference : [How to push a docker image to Azure container registry using terraform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68580196/how-to-push-a-docker-image-to-azure-container-registry-using-terraform)